# How to use a variable value

Tags: xslt

The variable behaviour here does not work as expected.
I have a variable named fonttag with a value that is an HTML line with both start and end tags and a divider.

```
<xsl:variable name="fonttag">
    <font face="ANGSANA NEW" size="12">|</font>
</xsl:variable>
```

When I try to use it, to get part of the string back, I get an empty string:

```
<xsl:value-of select="substring-before($fonttag ,'|')"/>
```

Where I expected the substring :

```
<font face="ANGSANA NEW" size="12">
```

Similarly the

```
<xsl:value-of select="$fonttag"/>
```

returns nothing, although

```
<xsl:copy-of select="$fonttag"/>
```

return the whole string. Is there another way to achieve the expected result ?

**A derived-question**: Is it possible to nest xsl select tags like this (cannot get it to work either)

```
<xsl:copy-of select="substring-before( <xsl:copy-of select="$fonttag"/>,'|')"/>
```

?

thanks

Comment: You are not setting a string value to your variable... it is a node set in this case, that's why `substring()` won't operate and `copy-of` does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am afraid you misunderstand how XSLT works. Your variable does not contain the **string** `"<font face="ANGSANA NEW" size="12">|</font>"`. It contains the **element** `font`, with two attributes, and the string value of `"|"`. The `xsl:value-of` instruction, as well as any string function such as `substring()`, only address the [string value](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#dt-string-value) of the given expression.

Comment: Allright, so I would need to add the <font> tag as a Text string instead. Or would there be a more natural XLST way of achiving the same thing

Comment: ok, with that info i got it to work by declaring the variable with <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;font face="ARIAL" size="12">|&lt;/font></xsl:text> instead thanks

Comment: @Christian  You didn't tell us what that thing you're trying to achieve is. But I am sure there is a **much** better way than working with escaped strings.

Comment: Well ok, I'm trying to parse an XML and based on the attributes insert several start tags before parsing the child element and lastly inserting the corrosponding end tags. It's inserting the right end tags that is really problematic as they will vary dynamically so its not know before hand which end tags that will be needed. First I tried to call a new template that would insert the next tags and then call the child elements, but ran into problems as the "context" was not passed along so i could not get to the childs.

Comment: @Christian I am afraid I don't follow you at all. As I said earlier, I believe you are missing the basic concepts of how XSLT works. XSLT processes the XML **after** it has been already parsed. You do not "insert tags" in XSLT; you create the result by outputting **nodes**.

Comment: Hi sry, I may not explain it right then ;) Im, new at XSL obviously but do know function based programming. The tags I insert is in an output file in HTML format not the original XML. I have made it work now even though it may not be the prettiest XSL ever, the tips provided here helped a lot so thanks. It turned out that whenever i used a variable containing a string with some of theese angle bracket inserted using CDATA I had to add DOE. as in  <xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select="substring-before($text,$replace)"/> Im reading up on XSL parallel to this ;)

Comment: "*whenever i used a variable containing a string with some of theese angle bracket*" You should never have to do that.